# Windows Phone - Making Page Scrollable

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have the following code in xaml file of windows phone app:

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">            

                <Button Content="Save Details" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,870,0,0" Name="Button_SaveDetails" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" />
                <Button Content="Cancel" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="296,870,0,0" Name="Button_Cancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Now, even though the page is scrollable, I have two problems:

1) Some of the contents appear behind the application title
2) The buttons at the bottom are not fully visible (does not scroll entirely to the bottom)

Here is a screenshot showing the first problem

[image]

How can I solve these two problems please?  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want to do is move the scroll viewer so that it is the top most element. Then put the grid inside of that. Don't have a grid surrounding the scroll viewer. From what code you posted I believe that is your issue.